# Error received when running missForest: Error in if (xi > xj) 1L else -1L : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, missing-data, imputation

I have a dataset that contained missing values, I have split my dataset into test and train first and wanted to impute the train dataset using missForest.

```
library(missForest)

train_impute<- train[-c(1:3)] # "-c(1:3)" removing id variables prior to imputation

summary(train_impute)

train_imp<- missForest(train_impute)
```

I used the code above as I am new to missForest and wanted to test out the imputation and how it works. Prior to this I have made sure to change my variables to their proper structure (e.g., factor vs numerical variables). However, when running the missForest command I get the following error:

```
Error in if (xi > xj) 1L else -1L : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed.
```

I am unsure why I am receiving this error or how I can resolve this issue.

A little information about my data:
for my train set I have *43217 obs and 71 variables*. Not all of my variables have missing values (e.g., Age, race etc).
My target variable which is lung cancer status also has 0 missing values.

I have tried using `is.na(train_impute)` but I am not sure how that will help my problem. I am thinking using an if and else statement my work in this case but I would like other suggestions as well.

Comment: I have gotten the same error, but it is solved after I make the data into a data frame again. e.g. train_impute <-as.data.frame(train_impute), then run the missForest again. I can't figure out the reason.